# Can I run wepack or browserify on iOS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, browserify

I am sorry that this question sound very silly but I want to develop a website using React on my iPad. But in order to run react I need Browserify or Webpack to compile react code. So is there any way of doing without the use of computer?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can run webpack or browserify on ios. On an ipad, im not sure. If you have access to a terminal on your ipad, then its feasible, but its hard to really k now without knowing the permissions issues that can occur.

I also strongly advise not building on your ipad, if you have some sort of text editor, then go ahead and code.

You can also code react without a build system

> While React can be used without a build pipeline, we recommend setting
>   it up so you can be more productive. A modern build pipeline typically
>   consists of:
>
> A package manager, such as Yarn or npm. It lets you take advantage of
>   a vast ecosystem of third-party packages, and easily install or update
>   them. A bundler, such as webpack or Browserify. It lets you write
>   modular code and bundle it together into small packages to optimize
>   load time. A compiler such as Babel. It lets you write modern
>   JavaScript code that still works in older browsers.